# How to add design dependency in android studio 3.0. its not working in standard way

Tags: android

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {  
    compileSdkVersion 26 
    defaultConfig {  
        applicationId "com.example.rohit.ironman"  
        minSdkVersion 15  
        targetSdkVersion 26  
        versionCode 1  
        versionName "1.0"  
        testInstrumentationRunner"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"  
    }  
    buildTypes {  
        release {  
            minifyEnabled false  
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'  
        }  
    }  
}  
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-beta1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.1'
}
```

I have also tried-
Implementation `'com.android.support:design:26.1.1'`
instead of
compile `'com.android.support:design:26.1.1'` 
but still the gradle sync fails
my gradle version is 4.1
android plugin version is 3.0.1

Comment: can you tell the error that's coming

Comment: Have all supported and design library same version

Answer (score 2):

Use The method to add Android default librarys like **support,design,core,..** library

- Open your project in Android Studio
- Right-click your app in project view and select "Open Module Settings"
- Click the "Dependencies" tab and then the '+' button
- Select "Libary Dependency"
- Select Required Library fom the List

Answer (score 1):

add this in build gradle of app

```
repositories {
mavenCentral()
maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
```

}

and in build script of whole app

```
 buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }

}
```

for more info about what changes are made just read here https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html

Answer (score 0):

You are using Google's support library as dependancy. And when you upgrade to Android Studio 3.0, Google's maven repository central is required if you want to use these library.

See this link for more details: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies.html#google-maven

Simply follow the migration instruction, add `google()` in the build.gradle file and sync again.

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    google()

    // If you're using a version of Gradle lower than 4.1, you must instead use:
    // maven {
    //     url 'https://maven.google.com'
    // }
    // An alternative URL is 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/'
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

> Try to add the missing code from here

```
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
            google()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
            classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
    }

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://jitpack.io"
        }
        google()
    }
}
```

[image]

> and add this to your `build.gradle(Module:app)`

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:27.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.1'
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

just refractor it

Refractor<<migrate to android X

Comment: refractor<migrate to android x

Answer (score 0):

Just to improve on @Tomin B Azhakathu answers to tackle design library particularly. Follow these steps:

- Right-click your app in project view and select
- Select Open Module Settings
- Click the "Dependencies" tab
- Then click the '+' button on below the "Declared Dependencies"
- Select "Libary Dependency"
- Enter "design" on the search form and hit enter key
- On the returned result select the Library with Artifact = "design" and Group ID = "com.android.support"
- Click on ok and Synch your grade if need be.

> PS: This is Legacy Library now, you may need to migrate to AndroidX

Answer (score 0):

You can't add design dependency in implementation, instead of we can use material dependency:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
```